# Regular expression to change Ingredient 1 TO "Ingredient" + counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to change just the `label` tag when I clone the div. The current piece of JS changes the product name within the drop down list.

`var clone = $('#product-1').clone(false)[0].outerHTML.replace(/1/g, counter);`

```
<div class="activeingredients">
    <div class="products" id="product-1">
        <label>Active Ingredient 1</label>
        <ul>
            <li style="display:inline-block">
                <select name="productid">
                    <option>Product 1</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ehv1xmL6/

Thanks

Comment: `var clone = $('#product-1').clone(false)[0].outerHTML.replace(/Ingredient 1/g, "Ingredient " + counter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, including just having a string without a number ready to replace the label text. However, following what you already have I made the following changes:

I first added a class to the label to make it easier to select. Your current code selects all numbers inside the div.

```
<label class="ingredientLabel">Active Ingredient 1</label>
```

Second, I cloned the div. Then selected the html inside of .ingredientLabel and changed the number using Regex. I changed the regex to find any number inside the string and not just '1' in case the number changes for some reason.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    $("#addproduct").click(function(){
        counter+= 1;
        var clone = $('#product-1').clone(false);
        clone.find(".ingredientLabel").html(clone.find(".ingredientLabel").html().replace(/[0-9]+/g, counter));
        $(clone).appendTo(".activeingredients")
    });
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehv1xmL6/3/)